# Como hago para remplazar los valores minimos de una fecha por un string vacio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice

Tengo un programa lo cual llama a un servicio al ejecutarse me da como resultado ciertos valores y estos son guardados en un archivo csv. Uno de esos valores es una fecha la cual cuando esta vacia me muestra 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM como valor minimo.

Lo que quisera es que en antes que me muestre el resultado, poder remplazar esta fecha por un valor nullo o vacio para no tener que mostrar esa fecha con valores que pueden confundir al usuario.

Este es parte de mi codigo:

```
newLine = string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\"",


    item.InvitationDate, //Convert.ToDateTime(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.InvitationDate) ? "" : 
    item.Reminder1SentDate);
```

Como ven el campo `item.invitationDate` es el cual me da como resultado lo que indico mas arriba. Despues del comentario es lo que he intentado de hacer pero no he tenido exito

Gracias

Comment: En que lenguaje estas trabajando?? parace javascript o c#

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia en las etiquetas está marcado como C#

Comment: El de abajo tiene la razón

Comment: @Flxtr, muchas gracias tienes toda la razon. Si me funciono!

Comment: @Flxtr si!! por favor. Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que tienes un `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`, eso significa que tienes el valor mínimo asignado a tu variable de tipo `DateTime`.

Para solucionarlo, simplemente debes comparar contra ese valor, por ejemplo:

```
newLine = string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\"",
item.InvitationDate, (item.InvitationDate == DateTime.MinValue ? string.Emtpy : item.InvitationDate.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad `InvitationDate` tiene que ser [nullable](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) para poder lograr lo que quieres. En tu caso, cuando no inicializas un valor la propiedad `InvitationDate`, valor por defecto que se asigna es 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

Convierte la propiedad en nullable y asi podras saber si es null, entonces mostrar un espacio vacio.

En la clase donde esta definida la propiedad, la defines como nullable asi:

```
public class TuClase
{
   //...
   public DateTime? InvitationDate {get;set;}
}
```

Entonces al momento de hacer el format seria asi:

```
newLine = string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\"",
    item.InvitationDate.HasValue ? item.InvitationDate.ToString() : String.Empty, 
    item.Reminder1SentDate);
```

Comment: En eso tienes razon. Es mucho mejor verificar por el valor minimo que cambiar a nullable.